# Windows sleep even for UWP apps

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, uwp, sleep

In my app I have UP and DOWN channels which continuously listen for Audio stream.
I want to know that In windows is there any event which will tell me that machine is now going to sleep state (not sign-out because machine will go to sleep after sign-out based on the user settings) so that i can suspend the channels and once machine wake-up(Not sign-in because machine wake up before the sign-in even) then i can resume it again.

Something similar to Cortana
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no 'sleep' relevant APIs for you to detect if the windows will go to sleep in UWP.

If you check the [Windows 10 universal Windows platform (UWP) app lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#a-little-history), you will find that Suspending and Resuming are the right events to listen to.

Comment: I am aware of Suspend and Resume event in UWP, I can not suspend the channels on these events because minimizing the app or switching the app is very frequent. Is something possible in C#, I can use DesktopExtension to hock up an event.

Comment: What did you mean about 'use DesktopExtension to hock up an event.'? According to UWP app lifecycle, if the windows will be going to sleep, the UWP app also will be in 'Not Running' status, before the 'Not Running', the app should go through a 'Suspending' status, you could be able to do some operations in it.